# Client-Side Rendering/JS Link documentation?

Tags: 2013, jslink

Has there been any sort of documentation or anything like that released for SharePoint 2013 Client-Side Rendering/JS Link?

Anthing unofficial?
Any dates for when documentation might be released?

Comment: They never did with SP2010, so I highly doubt that they will with SP2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj246996(v=office.15).aspx

I think I found the answer, I've posted it here for anyone else looking at the same issue.

Comment: Are your kidding? This is JSOM documentation. Neither Client Side Rendering nor JSLink are covered.

Answer (score 25):

### Some resources about Client Side Rendering

- [INTRODUCTION TO CLIENT-SIDE RENDERING IN SHAREPOINT 2013](http://www.rbradbrook.co.uk/blog/2013/04/14/introduction-to-client-side-rendering-in-sharepoint-2013/) - I would suggest to use this great article as a starting point, it goes through what CSR is, how CSR can be used, and some tips about debugging and developing
- As a primer on how to customize a field type by using CSR there is an article in MSDN  [How to: Customize a field type using client-side rendering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj220061.aspx) and a [sample code](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2013-Customize-0c9698e1) for it. An article [How to: Extend the Geolocation field type using client-side rendering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/jj163799.aspx) which describes how to customize the rendering of a field in list/view
- Take a look at post [Customize the rendering of a List View in Sharepoint 2013: Displaying List Items in Accordion](http://blog.vgrem.com/2013/04/14/customize-the-rendering-of-a-list-view-in-sharepoint-2013-displaying-list-items-in-accordion/) in my blog which describes how to customize list view via client side rendering

**Update**

[Andrey Markeev](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/1430/andrey-markeev) also posted a series of articles about CSR, highly recommended:

- [SharePoint 2013 Client Side Rendering: List Views](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views)
- [SharePoint 2013 Client Side Rendering: List Forms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/610259/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Forms)

Answer (score 22):

**7 Code samples that cover Client-Side Rendering/JS Link usage scenarios:**  http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a

Answer (score 7):

Here is a complete Tutorial on JS Link with few examples that you can use -

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/04/13/sharepoint-2013-js-link-tutorial/

Answer (score 6):

Not sure how much does it respond to your need for documentation, I've got an article written a while back with code sources for download. You could do quite a lot just be using that http://nettitude.wordpress.com/2013/01/27/creating-a-carousel-in-a-sharepoint-app-using-client-side-rendering/

Answer (score 5):

[These are **seven code samples** that will help you to learn all things related to the SharePoint 2013 Client-Side Rendering](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a)

Answer (score 1):

Here are the resources that I have found most useful:

- [Client Side Rendering (CSR) Demystified](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/SharePoint-Conference/2014/SPC318) -  I found this presentation really helpful in terms of giving me a general overview and would recommend watching this first
- [JSLink and CSR on idubbs.com](http://www.idubbs.com/blog/js-link-and-csr/)  - A selection of articles by the speaker in the presentation above.
- [JSLink and Display Templates on martinhatch.com](http://www.martinhatch.com/2013/08/jslink-and-display-templates-part-1.html) - A five part tutorial getting started with JSLink.
- [CSR Code Samples on Microsoft Office Dev Center](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a) - More examples if you need them.

I should also add that I got a bit confused originally with the difference between CSR/JSLink and using the Javascript Object Model (JSOM). They both use javascript but are different in terms of how they work and what they achieve. Those links above are for CSR not the JSOM.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete Tutorial on JS Link with example that you can use -

http://www.rbradbrook.co.uk/blog/2013/04/14/introduction-to-client-side-rendering-in-sharepoint-2013/