# Sharepoint - Link to other list with filter

Tags: list

I have two lists in SharePoint:

Products:

```
| ID | Name   |
| 1  | Apple  |
| 2  | Banana |
```

Orders:

```
| ID | Name   | Quantity |
| 1  | Apple  | 23       |
| 2  | Banana | 12       |
| 3  | Apple  | 45       |
```

How can I create a column in my products list with a link to the orders list that automatically filters to the selected product?

Answer (score 1):

I would try adding a calculated field on the Product list, and use it to build a link to the Order one.

Let's start from the url.

```
"http://someSite:somePort/Lists/Order/AllItems.aspx?View={ViewId}&FilterField1={ProductFieldName}&FilterValue1={ProductValue}"
```

By using a query string like the one above you can create an url that will link to the Orders list and apply the required product filter. You can confirm the actual field name and view id by looking at the address bar after you manually applied a filter on the list from the web UI.

After that, the idea is to create a formula on the Product list that would build the link based on the list item specified product.

A formula like

```
=CONCATENATE("<a href='http://someSite:somePort/Lists/Order/AllItems.aspx
      ?View={ViewId}&FilterField1={ProductFieldName}&FilterValue1=",
      {ProductFieldName},"' target='_blank'>",'go to product orders',"</a>")
```

should do the trick. Just chose number/date time as the field type.

Another more advanced option if you are working on SharePoint 2013 would be using jslink. This will require a bit more effort but will probably be more robust in the long run.

Jslink, also know as client side field rendering allows for javascript based modifications to the way a field is rendered. [This post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/73654/client-side-rendering-js-link-documentation) contains a lot of resources to get you started should you decide to go that route. Also, fell free to ask for clarifications and I will try to post some more details as soon as I can.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried to make a link trough concatenate but i get a syntax error.. (i'm using sharepoint in office 2013). i tried this: =CONCATENATE("<a href='http://google.com","Test","</a>") But i get this error: [Screenshot in german](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/adsejb9g9wjpy5v/Screenshot%202016-02-01%2023.10.34.png)

Comment: That would be the generic "Something went wrong" error page, right? You get it when you are creating the column? I have tried using a formula like yours on my standalone SharePoint 2013 development environment and it worked as expected. Notice that your sample in the comment above is incorrect - you are missing part of the tag. Try with **=CONCATENATE("<a href='......' >","Test","</a>")**

Comment: Also confirm that you are using a Calculated Column and that the result type is set to either number or datetime. BTW, I had to fix the reply above - I tested the formula in my environment and noticed that I had the two parameters in the query string wrong. It is FilterField**1** and FilterValue**1** - notice the added "1" at the end