# JS Link and CSR: Error After Filtering and Viewing/Editing

Tags: javascript, jslink, client-side-rendering

I have a *.js to color code my rows according to the value of the column `Status`. It is working very fine UNLESS one filters any column and views/edits an item.
After exiting the item view, the following error occurs:

```
TypeError: Unable to get value of the property `style`: object is null or undefined
```

It seems that the last row (see my full code below) `row.style.backgroundColor = statusColors[status];` does cause the error.

Is there any alternative to OnPostRender?

```
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
  OnPostRender: function(ctx) {

    var statusColors =  {
        'Accepted' : '#ccff99',  
        'Superseded' : '#ffb366',
        'Pending' : '#ffff66',
        'Delivered' : '#4bb84f',
        'Rejected' : '#ff6666'
    };

    var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
    for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
    {
        var status = rows[i]["Status"];
        var rowId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
        var row = document.getElementById(rowId); 
        row.style.backgroundColor = statusColors[status];
    }   
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you overriding the View or item or none of them in your template overrides? Your logic can possbily be moved to the item override function where you set the background colout accodring to the status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replicate the issue by placing **two** views in a Page. OnPostRender is applied to all.

One View will color correct, the other will give the `.style is undefined error`

> It is because the `ctx` object is a (window) **global** Object
>   which SharePoint (ab)uses for **all** CSR transformations.

So on first run all is fine

Then SharePoint processes the next View and thus 'destroys' your precious `ctx` Object from the previous View

Writing `function( MYctx )` will not help, as JavaScript always **passes Objects by reference**

To be correct `function( ctx )` is senseless, it is the same as `function()`, because `ctx` is a **global**

#### Method 1

To workaround your issue you have to store the `ids` in your own object, then in the OnPostRender proces your own object.

Note that OnPostRender fires on every View Refesh, coloring (already colored) TRs over and over again.

#### Method 2

Involves code you put in the Field render, which waits for the DOM to be painted, then applies the color. I wrote about this earlier: [Highlight Sharepoint List based on condition](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/172325/highlight-sharepoint-list-based-on-condition/172345#172345)

```
var iid = GenerateIID();
var daysleft = 80;
_spYield(function(){
    var row = document.getElementById(iid);
    if (daysleft < 90) row.style.backgroundColor = "lightcoral";          
},20);
```

#### Method 3

In the [iCSR framework](http://iCSR.github.io) I do not use OnPostRender at all for this coloring stuff.
It is easier to insert a blank image in the Field with an `onload` event to color its own! parent TR, same technique I used for many years in the [Calculated Column ViewMasters](http://viewmaster365.com/#/How)

#### Method 4

If in our case you are not dealing with multiple Views.

Your TR rows are already colored on the first run

The easiest ductape patch might be to check

```
  var TR=document.getElementById(row.iid);
  if (TR) TR.style.backgroundColor = color;
```

*I have not tested this, could be MDS issues*