# How to show/hide columns in OOTB SharePoint 2013 List form?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, javascript

I have a requirement to make a SharePoint List Form where I have 50+ fields where  fields are hidden in the beginning but if a user checks a box then the related fields shows up. I know I can achieve this with jQuery/javascript, but will that be a recommended way to do that for 50+ fields? Or there is any other option? I am debating between creating a form in Visual Studio or in SharePoint Designer with jQuery. Can someone please let me know what is the correct way to start creating this form?

Thank you for your help in advance.

-Nidhi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Infopath or Client Side Rendering (JS Link) for hiding the columns of the SharePoint List.

for better understanding follow this blog using CSR
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSR-code-samples-11-Fully-54ebcaa6

To understand CSR well, you can follow this link
[Client-Side Rendering/JS Link documentation?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/73654/client-side-rendering-js-link-documentation)

Comment: +1 for CSR.  You can do quite a bit leveraging the CSR framework, and the List Form Web Part even includes a JSLink field to make it easy to attach your CSR script.

Comment: Thank you Rishabh and Dylan for your reply. I will give it a try. We don't want to use InfoPath, otherwise I know it will be piece of cake :-). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with using JavaScript. Almost everything in SharePoint (frontend-wise) is handled with JavaScript anyway. And it would be, by far, the fastest way to do it.

SPUtility.js would be a good candidate for a library that brings all the functions you need: https://github.com/kitmenke/sputility

Comment: Great! Thank you Daniel for your answer! I was thinking to do it FrontEnd development but wasn't 100% sure! Will try it out and let you know!