# SharePoint 2013 List Styling

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, list-view, custom-list

I want to change list view style for all Custom List and document library. Kindly can somebody help me with example.

Please guide if you have any article link.

Comment: Do you mean using the out of the box styles that are found when modifying the list / library views or do you mean doing something more with code?

Comment: Yes, I mean ListView of document library & custom list. I want to change look and feel with css or xslt

Comment: Check out what you can do with Client Side Rendering (CSR)
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/73654/client-side-rendering-js-link-documentation

Comment: Is possible without javascript as i want to change look and feel of each and every list in the whole SharePoint with same look and feel

Comment: For that you would use the site themes. Documentation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/sites/themes-overview 
Tutorial: http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/06/03/create-custom-theme-in-sharepoint-2013-step-by-step-tutorial/

Comment: This looks promising. Kindly put it as answer so I can assign it as answer. Thank you very much you are, You are savior of my day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try taking a look at site themes

Documentation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/sites/themes-overview

Tutorial: http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/06/03/create-custom-theme-in-sharepoint-2013-step-by-step-tutorial/